# Embed a webpage and run a javascript file on it

Tags: javascript, embed, html

I am basically trying to show end users a demonstration of how their webpage will look after they use my service[This would be a javascript file to run on their webpage.]

I have tried the following:

1. Used iframe to embed the webpage - The problem here is that i cant access the iframe content and run my js functions on them.
2. used jquery load(), html embed, and object but the same problem persists. i am unable to run my javascript on the embedded webpage.

Basically what i want to do can be seen here http://www.luminate.com/publisher/  . Just type in a website URL in the Preview Luminate section and see what happens. The page loads in a new tab and they have loaded a javascript on pageload.

Can someone suggest any way to do this or what these guys have done[ http://www.luminate.com/publisher/ ]?

Answer (score 0):

here is the script which they used to call the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pop_demo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $("#preview-site-url").val();
    if (!url) {
        alert("Please enter a URL to preview.");
        return false;
    }
    if (!/^(http|https):\/\//.test(url)) {
        url = "http://" + url;
    }
    url = "/publisher/demo/?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url);
    window.open(url, "");
}
```

Here your calling url : "/publisher/demo/?url
and internally it get load frame and pass the result to next page.

Comment: Thanks kiran for tsking your time to answer this, but i am still stuck.. could you elaborate "internally it get load frame and pass the result to next page." part?

Comment: I need to load a java script as well, in addition to loading the page in a new tab. How to call the javascript?